# How to manually include external aar package for Modules?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm having my main project include a Module Project(that is basically another project within the main project)
sort of like an SDK

that module has it's own Gradle files etc.
how do i manually include an AAR file specifically to that module project ?

if i simply include it by adding

```
buildscript {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    repositories {
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
}
```

and adding

```
implementation(name:'arrName-1.0.1', ext:'aar')
```

and even heaving the libs folder (with the arr file inside)
in the module directory
it will issue a build fail with:

```
ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :arrName-1.0.1:.
```

i think no matter what i do
when i include the

```
flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
```

even if i do it in the Module (sdk) Gradle file
it will still go looking for it in the main project directory, and not in the module directory

any ideas on how i can get the module only for the module one ? with hosting it in the module directorys and not the project directory ?